# Is there an XML node.firstChild equivalent in E4X?

Tags: xml, e4x

What would be the equivalent of node.firstChild in E4X? I do not see any articles mentioning what the equivalent would be.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `node.children()[0]` would do the same.